# Change Language in Every Activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

My **LocaleHelper class** I use to change the *language*.
[Github Code](https://github.com/gunhansancar/ChangeLanguageExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gunhansancar/changelanguageexample/helper/LocaleHelper.java)

In my **SecondActivity** class, when someone choose **english** for example.

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "en")
recreate()
```

But my issue is how to change **MainActivity** in **english**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Found a Solution by creating a new class for every Activity. You should make a new class for every activity, to take the instance of objects of Activities. After that work with cases. If something change call the setLocale(this, "languageCode"). Define this to your Activity class.

```
 fun setLocale(activity: Activity, languageCode: String?) {
        val locale = Locale(languageCode)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val resources = activity.resources
        val config = resources.configuration
        config.setLocale(locale)
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)

    }
```

Make a new class like this:

```
public class Main {
    public Main(MainActivity act, String s) {
        act.setLocale(act,s);
    }

}
```

and then call it like this when changes happen:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        var lang = SettingsActivity()
        if (lang.STH_CHANGE) {
            if (lang.ENGLISH) {
                val myobj = Main(this, "en")

            }
            if (lang.GREEK) {
                val myobj = Main(this, "gr")

            }
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

**SettingsActivity()** is my Activity where there is a button which changes to English-Greek.